# Question about intersection of an open interval and the complement of a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ a countable set, and $X = \mathbb{R} \setminus A$. Then we have to prove that

1. For all open interval $(a,b)$, the set $(a,b) \cap X$ is uncountable;
2. $X$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

That's what I did:

First, let's prove 2). Suppose that there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(a,b) \cap X = \emptyset$. So, $(a,b) \subset A$ (if there was a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $c \not \in A$, so $c \in X$, and then, $c \in (a,b) \cap X$). Since $A$ is countable, then $B \subset A$ is countable. It implies that $(a,b)$ is countable, and, we can show that's not true. So, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $(a,b) \cap X \not = \emptyset$, and $X$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, for proving 1., I tried to find a contradiction again. Suppose that there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the set $(a,b) \cap X$ is countable. So we have

- If, $(a,b) \cap X = \emptyset$, and, $(a,b) \subset A$ (then we can use the same argument that $(a,b)$ is not countable).
- But, what could I do if $(a,b) \cap X = \{x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n, \dots\}$, ie, $(a,b)\cap X$ is a countable set?

**EDIT:**

Since $A$ is countable, then $A\cap (a,b)$ is countable because $A \cap (a,b) \subset A$. If $(a,b) \cap X$ is countable, than, we can write
$$(a,b) = ((a,b) \cap A) \cup ((a,b)\cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus A)).$$
So, it implies that $(a,b)$ is an uncoutable set, and we can prove that is not true.

So, $(a,b) \cap X$ is an uncountable set.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: $A$ is countable, hence so is $A\cap (a,b)$. Now, if $(a,b)\cap X = (a,b)\setminus A$ is also countable, then $(a,b)$ is the union of two countable sets and therefore countable itself.

Comment: Are you saying that we can write $(a,b) = ((a,b) \cap A) \cup ((a,b) \setminus A)$ both of them countable?

Comment: Exactly that. :-)